# Make an element continue horizontally without dropping down (clearing)

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a website that I want to show content in horizontal fashion rather than vertically. Please don't lecture me on design standards and what not, its a personal site and I have a specific need this functionality.

As an example, I have a header that is always centered on the page (fixed). Same with the footer. The content section which sits in the middle will have its content added dynamically depending on what the user clicks. Think of it like an android LinearLayout that has its orientation horizontal.

The problem that is once an element reaches the right over the screen, it clears and starts a new line. I want it to continue left. I'm using a CSS content section of position: absolute, and display: inline-block; Then all the boxes added inside are position: relative, with clear: none. It's not getting the job done. Any tips on the CSS attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

...................

Comment: I've never heard of that property. Thanks so much! Do you happen to know of any sites that may have a list of lesser known properties such as this one?

Comment: You ought to know that property.  `white-space: pre` is the default style for the `<pre>` tag in X/HTML.  :)  You might try [W3Schools' CSS Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp)...

Comment: @spidy, http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/ is one option. Not by favorite, but it does the job.

Comment: I learned most of my CSS from w3schools. To be honest, I'm more of a Java, C#, Android developer but I'm not paying someone else to do a site.